# Load Content of Database in CKEditor, change it and save it

Tags: ckeditor

I try to program a page, where the content of the database will be loaded into the CKEditor then the content can be changed and saved again. The page is devided into different  areas and if the user doubleclicks on an area the Editor should appear. With the following Code, Loading the Content and Doubleclick works, but I can't find any solution to save it back to the database:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/MasterPageBasic.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditTemplate.aspx.cs" Inherits="Templates_EditTemplate" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="Styles/EditTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/EditTemplate.js" type="text/javascript" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <div id="header1" class="editable">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewHeader" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceHeader"
            DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="HeaderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Header") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceHeader" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Header] FROM [PageContent]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','navbar','',1)"
                    onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','navbar','','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')">
                    <img src="Images/Clean-Navigation-Bar-by-willyepp.png" alt="" name="navbar" border="0"
                        id="Articles" onload="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="sidebarLeft" class="editable">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewSidebarLeft" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSidebarLeft"
            DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="SidebarLeftTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SidebarLeft") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSidebarLeft" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [SidebarLeft] FROM [PageContent]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarRight" class="editable">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewSidebarRight" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSidebarRight"
            DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="SidebarRightTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SidebarRight") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSidebarRight" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [SidebarRight] FROM [PageContent]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="editable">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewContent" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceContent"
            DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ContentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Content") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceContent" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Content] FROM [PageContent]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="editable">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewFooter" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceFooter"
            DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorFooter" Text='<%# Bind("Footer") %>' runat="server"
                    CustomConfigurationsPath="../ckeditor/config.js" ToolbarSet="Footer" EditorAreaCSS="/css/editor.css"
                    Width="947px" Height="100px">   
                </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceFooter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Footer] FROM [PageContent]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

JS-File

```
    //<![CDATA[

// Uncomment the following code to test the "Timeout Loading Method".
// CKEDITOR.loadFullCoreTimeout = 5;


window.onload = function () {
    // Listen to the double click event.
    if (window.addEventListener)
        document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', onDoubleClick, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        document.body.attachEvent('ondblclick', onDoubleClick);

};

function onDoubleClick(ev) {

    // Get the element which fired the event. This is not necessarily the
    // element to which the event has been attached.
    var element = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

    // Find out the div that holds this element.
    var name;
    do {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    while (element && (name = element.nodeName.toLowerCase()) && (name != 'div' || element.className.indexOf('editable') == -1) && name != 'body')

    if (name == 'div' && element.className.indexOf('editable') != -1)
        replaceDiv(element, element.id);

}

var cke_header1;
var cke_sidebarLeft;
var cke_sidebarRight;
var cke_content;

function replaceDiv(div, id) {

    //First check if an editor is already open, if so close it
    if (cke_header1)
        cke_header1.destroy();
    if (cke_sidebarLeft)
        cke_sidebarLeft.destroy();
    if (cke_sidebarRight)
        cke_sidebarRight.destroy();
    if (cke_content)
        cke_content.destroy();

    switch (id) {
        case "header1":
            cke_header1 = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {
                height: "200", width: "950",
                language: 'en',
                uiColor: '#350e1e',
                toolbar: 'MyToolbar'
            });
            break;
        case "sidebarLeft":
            cke_sidebarLeft = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {
                height: "690", width: "180",
                language: 'en',
                uiColor: '#350e1e',
                toolbar: 'MyToolbar'
            });
            break;
        case "sidebarRight":
            cke_sidebarRight = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {
                height: "690", width: "180",
                language: 'en',
                uiColor: '#350e1e',
                toolbar: 'MyToolbar'
            });
            break;
        case "content":
            cke_content = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {
                height: "690", width: "500",
                language: 'en',
                uiColor: '#350e1e',
                toolbar: 'MyToolbar'
            });
            break;       
    }
}
```

So I tried to use only one FormView, now loading from database and save back works. But the Doubleclick to get the Editor doesn't work anymore. Also I can't save anymore if I add the link to the Javascript file. (I used the same one as below.
Does anyone has a solution for this?

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="Templates/Styles/EditTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/EditTemplate.js" type="text/javascript" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">

    <asp:FormView ID="FormViewPage" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePage" DefaultMode="Edit">

        <EditItemTemplate>

            <div id="header1" class="editable">
                <asp:TextBox ID="HeaderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Header") %>' />
            </div>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','navbar','',1)"
                    onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','navbar','','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')">
                    <img src="Templates/Images/Clean-Navigation-Bar-by-willyepp.png" alt="" name="navbar" border="0"
                        id="Articles" onload="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
            <div id="content" class="editable">
                <asp:TextBox ID="ContentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Content") %>' />
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarLeft" class="editable">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SidebarLeftTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SidebarLeft") %>' />
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarRight" class="editable">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SidebarRightTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SidebarRight") %>' Visible="True" />
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="editable">
                <asp:TextBox ID="FooterTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Footer") %>' />
            </div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                Text="Aktualisieren" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                CommandName="Cancel" Text="Abbrechen" />
        </EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePage" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Header], [Content], [SidebarLeft], [SidebarRight], [Footer] FROM [PageContent]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE PageContent SET Header = @Header, [Content] = @Content, SidebarLeft = @SidebarLeft, SidebarRight = @SidebarRight, Footer = @Footer">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Header" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Content" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SidebarLeft" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SidebarRight" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Footer" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```